# Silverlight .SVC not found on Windows 2008 R2 server

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I am new to Silver light.

I created a Domain Service class following instructions from "http://www.devtoolshed.com/tutorial-configuring-silverlight-4-entity-framework-and-wcf-ria-services-separate-component-assembli". This creates a .cs file.
Published it to local host. A .svc is created virtually. I directly accessed the service with "http://localhost/ConfiguratorTools_QA/ConfiguratorSalesTool-Web-ConfiguratorDomainService.svc" url.  I copied the published files to a colleague's machine and still see .svc created in the Microsoft.Net temporary files.
Copied all the published files to Windows 2008 R2, I don't see the virtual .svc created. I get following error:

> WebHost failed to process a request.  Sender Information:
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult/27803528 
>   Exception: System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): The service
>   '/ConfiguratorTools_QA/ClientBin/ConfiguratorSalesTool-Web-ProductsDomainService.svc'
>   does not exist. ---> System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException:
>   The service
>   '/ConfiguratorTools_QA/ClientBin/ConfiguratorSalesTool-Web-ProductsDomainService.svc'
>   does not exist.

Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.EntityFramework, System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, and System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server set to Copy Local: True?

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't have EntityFramework CopyLocal : True.